# Django UnicodeEncodeError, Apache2 with mod_wsgi on Debian lenny

Tags: django

I have a trouble with unicode filenames on production server. When I'm trying to save file UnicodeEncodeError exception occures. Devserver works fine.

All locales for www-data are 'en_US.UTF-8'.

Also, I wrote down in /etc/apache2/envvars

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8' 
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

it did not help.

locale.getdefaultlocale() was returning (None,None), then I add following lines to django.wsgi

```
os.environ['LANG']='en_US.UTF-8'
os.environ['LC_ALL']='en_US.UTF-8'
```

After it locale.getdefaultlocale() started to return ('en_US', 'UTF8')

I noticed that sys.getdefaultencoding() returns 'ascii' but I don't know how to fix it.

Traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  366.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  209.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  955.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_pencil/admin.py" in save_model
  52.             super(PictureAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  709.         obj.save()
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1576.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  909.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  872.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  249.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_resized/forms.py" in save
  31.         super(ResizedImageFieldFile, self).save(name, new_content, save)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  44.         name = self.get_available_name(name)
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in get_available_name
  70.         while self.exists(name):
File "/home/myproject/myproject.com/python/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in exists
  230.         return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py" in exists
  171.         st = os.stat(path)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/django_pencil/picture/add/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 58-65: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 5):

also add to django.wsgi:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

simple sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') will not help, reload is important
This is python 2.x problem, not the django

Comment: Now sys.getdefaultencoding() returns 'utf-8', but  UnicodeEncodeError still happens.

Comment: in django_resized/forms.py you have to encode string to utf: super(ResizedImageFieldFile, self).save(name.encode('utf-8'), new_content, save)
and sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') must exists too...

Comment: When os.stat is called path already in unicode. I did try, but result is the same.

Comment: checkout - before called super(ResizedImageFieldFile is there  default encoding is still utf8? i am solve such python unicode problems for me by inserting setdefaultencoding in the settings.py file (because it will be called before any other parts of app)

Comment: This technique also works for Flask running with mod_wsgi. By default mod_wsgi redirects all print to stdout to its own log file (with encoding Latin-1). By doing this, output will be printed to the same terminal as the server was started from (if using mod_wsgi-express) and will render properly (if encoded to utf-8 when being printed).

Answer (score 0):

Debian doesn't I believe use '/etc/apache2/envvars'. Setting these values from inside of the Python script will not work as it will not initialise some things that only occur at process startup.

You either need to set the variables in the init.d startup script for Apache if envvars not consulted, or use mod_wsgi 3.4 and use daemon mode, setting the 'lang' and 'locale' options to WSGIDaemonProcess directive.

Comment: I use daemon mode, but seems mod_wsgi is too old
(ii  libapache2-mod-wsgi       2.5-1~lenny1) Also I did check /etc/init.d/apache2 file - it is binary.